# Realtime Mongo aggregation is slow

Tags: mongodb, analytics, aggregation-framework, dashboard

I am developing the dashboard of our application and I was wondering if it's normal for MongoDB to be so slow for some query aggregate queries.  I am pasting below a simplified version of one of our queries:

```
db.data_items.aggregate([
  {'$match': 
    {
     'organization_subscription_waves.wave_id':ObjectId('5617fe6abecf0500f9c6e125')
  }, 
  {'$group': 
    {'_id': '$data_type_value_type', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}
  }
])
```

The result is this:

```
{ "_id" : "PHOTO", "count" : 76 }
{ "_id" : "MULTI_SELECT", "count" : 1607 }
{ "_id" : "TIME", "count" : 659 }
{ "_id" : "MULTIPLE_CHOICE", "count" : 78321 }
{ "_id" : "DATE", "count" : 649 }
{ "_id" : "NUMBER", "count" : 2679 }
```

and takes over two minutes which I believe it's too long for such a simple aggregation.  I am wondering if there is anything I can do to improve the query efficiency or whether I must do some offline optimization to improve the performance.

Among others, I have this index on the collection:

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "name" : "organization_subscription_waves.wave_id_1",
  "key" : {
    "organization_subscription_waves.wave_id" : 1
  },
  "ns" : "gigwalk_apps_1.data_items"
},
```

Yet I am not sure if it's being used.  explain has the following output:

```
{
"stages" : [
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "query" : {
                "organization_subscription_waves.wave_id" : ObjectId("5617fe6abecf0500f9c6e125")
            },
            "fields" : {
                "data_type_value_type" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "plan" : {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "organization_subscription_waves.wave_id" : [
                        [
                            ObjectId("5617fe6abecf0500f9c6e125"),
                            ObjectId("5617fe6abecf0500f9c6e125")
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "allPlans" : [
                    {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "organization_subscription_waves.wave_id" : [
                                [
                                    ObjectId("5617fe6abecf0500f9c6e125"),
                                    ObjectId("5617fe6abecf0500f9c6e125")
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$data_type_value_type",
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : {
                    "$const" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: How big is your data set? If its massive it might take 2 minutes. The answer to this is probably sharding and/or indexing.

Comment: Also, I *think* the `BtreeCursor` implies an index is being user, but not sure.